# Систематизация прайс-листов

Tags: woocommerce, php

Приветствую, народ. Привел меня к вам крайне важный для меня вопрос систематизации прайс-листов от разных поставщиков в один единый файл для интернет-магазина на WooCommerce 2.1.12.

Представьте, что есть, к примеру, 5 поставщиков, которые продают один и тот же товар, но с разными ценами, немного разными наименованиями (заголовками) и в разной валюте (это я привел самый сложный вариант), и их нужно слить в один, с выбором определенного заголовка, преобразовать все валюты в одну и с выбором минимальной цены. Может, есть какой-то плагин или кто использует внешние инструменты?

Comment: Уникальное поле у товара есть? К примеру, у автозапчастей это сборный пара - артикул + бренд. У книг это ISBN?

Comment: @Pajerosport, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

Если нет уникальных полей (совокупности полей), то тут делается следующим образом.

1. Создается таблица своей номенклатуры.
2. Создается Кросс таблица с полями: номенклатура, поставщик, наименование номенклатуры у поставщика.
3. При загрузке прайса из файла сначала прогоняете его через кросс таблицу - приводите все наименования к своим и потом грузите все это в таблицу позиций прайс-листов.

**Обновление**

если вы пардон совсем в этом деле не шарите - то ищите программистов.
И еще момент - могут быть случаи задваивания номененклатуры (снача ввели -хлеб белый, а потом через месяц -белый хлеб 400г. А по сущности это один товар). Так вот даже после того как вы реализуете механизм (купите, сами напишите) - все равно прийдется переодически просматривать и настраивать кросс-таблицы

Comment: спасибо.только я как новичек не знаю как все это реализовать. пока работаю с 1 поставщиком и 300 товарами. хочется расшириться

Comment: Очевидно, что для написания или изменения программной части магазина надо обратиться к программистам.

Answer (score 1):

Ищите общее поле у товаров от различных поставщиков типа Код товара, Артикул, Serial number и т.п. Если найдете у всех, то слить вполне реально. Если нет, то машина не поймет, что "Товар 1" и "Первый товар" - это одно и то же. Готовых плагинов под все это я не встречал, надо заказывать разработку.